# communicate with server to edit a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, server

I want to have a program that is run in console communicate with a server. I have the url of my website which I can access through ssh but I want this program to be able to work without logging in so that I could give the program to other people without having any security concerns. In particular I'd like this program to be able to write to a file that is on the server. I was considering using form filling but this doesn't seem to work.

Here is a specific example of the kind of thing I want to do. The server has a file on it called count.txt that contains the number 0. The program when run communicates with the server is some manner so that the text file on the server has the number incremented by 1. So if I were to run the program 10 times it would have the number 10 in the file.

Here is another example, I run the program in console like this:
./myprogram Word
which would case Word to be written to the file

When this is done I want to be able to do ./myProgram in my console and have this happen. I shouldn't have to be logged into the server.

Any links to explanations of how to do this would be great. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be more usual to have an `http://yoursite.com/increment` style URL, which would have PHP code behind it that respond to requests by updating the file and (perhaps) returning the new value? Other people could then use this service by either entering the URL directly in their browser's address bar, or by making an http request from the programming language of their choice.

Comment: I was giving a specific and very simple example of what i want. more generally I might want to be able to have a user get a word written to the file for example

Comment: Then `http://yoursite.com/update?word=something`. Or, better, accept http POST requests with the data in whatever format you want. In a general sense, I don't understand why you would want the user to be able to update resources on your server through any mechanism other than a simple http request - if you wrote a program of your own that ran client-side to communicate with the server than your program would just be making http requests behind the scenes to tell the server to update the file, wouldn't it?

Comment: if that would work then thats exactly what I want, I don't know how to do that though so if you want you can answer my question by explaining how to do that

Comment: maybe give example code for the php

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but I know PHP (like all other server-side languages) has a mechanism to extract request parameters by name from the request, so in my second comment's example you'd check for a `"word"` parameter and then write its value to a file. Any number of introductory PHP tutorials should cover handling request parameters.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give that a try, if you want credit for answering my question write some kind of answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what nnnnnn is saying you would send your http request as

```
    http://yoursite.com/update.php?key=value
```

In your update.php application you would extract that value using

```
    $_GET['key'];
```